# I have flagged a question as a duplicate. The flag was marked as "helpful". But the question still hasn't closed

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

Yesterday (6/9/21), a question was asked: [How to remove the new weather info from the taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1655569/how-to-remove-the-new-weather-info-from-the-taskbar).

I have flagged this question as an *exact* duplicate of: [How can I disable the “News and Interests” Widget on the Windows 10 Taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1649169/how-can-i-disable-the-news-and-interests-widget-on-the-windows-10-taskbar)

My flag was marked a "helpful"
[image]

However, the question that was asked yesterday still hasn't been closed as a duplicate. **Why wasn't this question closed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you flagged is still in the closure review queue: https://superuser.com/review/close/1062030

As *someone* thought that the flag had merit in being a duplicate it may be that the closure flag was deemed "valid" and therefore marked "helpful" by the system.

No human moderator has been involved in handling anything other than comment flags on either question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will you be able to close it since your a moderator?

Comment: Done. Not that it's going to change much. The more recent question presumably hit HNQ and/or coincided with a larger group of people getting that update.

Comment: Yeah, it was just a bit annoying, since the new question got a lot of attention while my didn't :-)

Comment: Also, it's interesting, after the new question was asked and _before_ I flagged it. My post started getting a few upvotes. I was wondering why, and then I saw the new post

Comment: @MendelG - You should get the joy of knowing you answered the question before anyone else.  Upvotes are meaningless at the end of the day.  Your answer is the superior answer, since you left absolutely no doubt, it was indeed that particular feature (IMO).

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks! I thought about that too. We're just here to help the community, The upvotes _don't_ really matter. It's just that I thought that _my_ post would get more attention, hence I have asked _and_ answered it on my own.